# Regex: include 3 word in front and 3 behind the selected text

Tags: regex, text, google-sheets

Im using this regex code in excel to find the desired text in a paragraph:

```
=RegexExtract(B2,"(bot|vehicle|scrape)")
```

This code will successfully return all 3 of the words if they are found on a paragraph, what I would like to do as an extra is for the regex to return the desired text in bold along with few words in front and 3 words in the back of the selected word.

Example of text:

```
A car (or automobile) is a wheeled motor vehicle used for transportation. 
Most definitions of car say they run primarily on roads, seat one to eight people,
have four tires, and mainly transport people rather than goods.
```

Example output:

```
a wheeled motor **vehicle** used for transportation
```

I want a portion of the text to appear in order for the receiver to be able to pinpoint easier the location of the text.

Any alternative approach is much appreciated.

Comment: Try `"((?:\w+(?:\W+\w+){0,2})?\W+(?:bot|vehicle|scrape)(?:\W+\w+(?:\W+\w+){0,2})?)"`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/EqgFdK/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Regex101 seems to find the match but excel returns a blank cell without errors.

Comment: See https://imgur.com/a/fRedZdQ

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Awesome, worked perfectly! Thanks for your help! Post it as answer bellow it deserves upvote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
=RegexExtract(B2,"(?:\w+\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,2})?(?:bot|vehicle|scrape)(?:\W+\w+(?:\W+\w+){0,2})?")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EqgFdK/3) and the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(%3F%3A%5Cw%2B%5CW%2B(%3F%3A%5Cw%2B%5CW%2B)%7B0%2C2%7D)%3F(%3F%3Abot%7Cvehicle%7Cscrape)(%3F%3A%5CW%2B%5Cw%2B(%3F%3A%5CW%2B%5Cw%2B)%7B0%2C2%7D)%3F):

[image]

**Details**: The pattern is enclosed with capturing parentheses to make `REGEXEXTRACT` actually extract the string you need that meets the following pattern:

- `(?:\w+\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,2})?` - an optional sequence of a word followed with non-word chars that is followed with zero, one or two repetitions of 1+ word chars and then 1+ non-word chars
- `(?:bot|vehicle|scrape)` - a `bot`, `vehicle` or `scrape` word
- `(?:\W+\w+(?:\W+\w+){0,2})?` - an optional sequence of 1+ non-word chars and then 1+ word chars followed with zero, one or two repetitions of 1+ non-word chars and then 1+ word chars.

Google Spreadsheets test:

[image]

Comment: @JohnCould I think this is all: note how the `\w+` and `\W+` alternate before the terms and after. They should interleave.